# How to test Salesforce flow iframe popup using UTAM (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, salesforce, e2e-testing

I am using [UTAM](https://utam.dev/salesforce/introduction) which is essentially wrapper over Seleniums created for Salesfroce testign giving you access to a lot of things so you don't have to implement them on your own.

In out SF instance we have a flow which creates an account, its a regular action that is configured to open a flow on click.

[image]

Upon clicking and iframe opens up. I can't open it in other non iframe way (or I don't know how).

[image]

Everything below the menu is an iframe.
The code inside the iframe is inside shadowdom.

```
<iframe force-alohapage_alohapage="" height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="yes" allowtransparency="true" name="vfFrameId_1696407089498" title="accessibility title" allowfullscreen="true" lang="en-US" allow="geolocation *; microphone *; camera *; display-capture *" tabindex="0">
#document
<html> ... <html>
</iframe>
```

Now I am trying to find the select element inside the frame.

```
    DesktopLayoutContainer layoutContainer = from(DesktopLayoutContainer.class);

    AppNavBar navBar = layoutContainer.getAppNav().getAppNavBar();
    navBar.getNavItem("Account").clickAndWaitForUrl("Account");

    ConsoleObjectHome c = from(ConsoleObjectHome.class);
    ActionsContainer a = c.getListView().getHeader().getActions();
    a.getActionLink("Create Partner Account").click();

    AlohaPage page = from(AlohaPage.class);
    // we have aloha page that finds the iframe

    String title = page.getAlohaPageFrame().getTitle(); // title is accessibility title so it finds the iframe
```

The I don't know what to do with this Aloha frame, it won't give me access to the iframe contents.

I also have access to the underlying web driver, and tried using selenium directly

```
    List<WebElement> frames = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe")); // finds 2 iframes

    for (int i = 0; i < frames.size(); i++) {
        driver.switchTo().frame(i); // breaks for index 1, "No iframe with index 1
        List<WebElement> objs = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
        List<?> selects = objs
                .stream()
                .filter(ob -> ob.getTagName().equals("select"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        // selects is always empty
    }
```

It will be best to make utam work with this, but I don't mind using the web driver as well.

EDIT: I managed to access the iframe like this

```
    WebElement iframe = driver
            .findElement(By.className("iframe-parent"))
            .findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));

    driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
   // here drivers sees all of the element in the frame
```

In order to exit the frame you can use

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```